# Can't use go tool pprof with an existing server

Tags: go, gorilla, pprof

I have an existing http server which I would like to profile. I have included `_ "net/http/pprof"`to my imports, and I already have http server running:

```
router := createRouter()
server := &http.Server {
    Addr:           ":8080",
    Handler:        router,
    ReadTimeout:    15*time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   15*time.Second,
//  MaxHeaderBytes: 4096,
}

log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```

When I'm trying to access http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/ I get `404 page not found`.

That's what I get when using `go tool pprof` on a local machine:

```
userver@userver:~/Desktop/gotest$ go tool pprof http://192.168.0.27:8080/
Use of uninitialized value $prefix in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/pprof line 3019.
Read http://192.168.0.27:8080/pprof/symbol
Failed to get the number of symbols from http://192.168.0.27:8080/pprof/symbol

userver@userver:~/Desktop/gotest$ go tool pprof http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/profile
Read http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/symbol
Failed to get the number of symbols from http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/symbol
```

Same for a remote client:

```
MacBookAir:~ apple$ go tool pprof http://192.168.0.27:8080/
Use of uninitialized value $prefix in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.2/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/pprof line 3027.
Read http://192.168.0.27:8080/pprof/symbol
Failed to get the number of symbols from http://192.168.0.27:8080/pprof/symbol
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but [`net/http/pprof`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof) only registers its handlers with `http.DefaultServeMux`.

From the [source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.9/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go#L72-L76):

```
func init() {
        http.Handle("/debug/pprof/", http.HandlerFunc(Index))
        http.Handle("/debug/pprof/cmdline", http.HandlerFunc(Cmdline))
        http.Handle("/debug/pprof/profile", http.HandlerFunc(Profile))
        http.Handle("/debug/pprof/symbol", http.HandlerFunc(Symbol))
        http.Handle("/debug/pprof/trace", http.HandlerFunc(Trace))
}
```

If you're not using the default mux you just have to register any/all of those you want with whatever mux you're using, e.g. something like `mymux.HandleFunc("…", pprof.Index)`, etc.

Alternatively you can listen on a separate port (also possibly bound to only localhost if desired) with the default mux as [you've shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30560860/55504).

Comment: I have a question: Once going to `/debug/pprof/` there are several links that lead to 404 pages. In particular `heap` and `allocs` 404. And as you've shown above, I don't see routes for those paths provided in `net/http/pprof/pprof.go`'s `init()` func. How do I make those accessible? Would you happen to know how I can get those @Dave C?

Comment: If you use `router.PathPrefix("/debug/").Handler(http.DefaultServeMux)` the heap endpoint is added. It's not if you apply the `init` handlers. Not sure why...

Comment: Note that when using Gorilla mux, there's a caveat - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71032595/485343) below for a workaround for the 404 errors.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using a `github.com/gorilla/mux.Router` you can simply hand off any request prefixed with `/debug/` to the `http.DefaultServeMux`.

```
import _ "net/http/debug"
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.PathPrefix("/debug/").Handler(http.DefaultServeMux)
```

Answer (score 14):

Looks like the problem was in a `*mux.Router` used from `github.com/gorilla/mux` which I used as a `Handler` in my `http.Server` instance.

Solution: just launch **one more** server just for the `pprof`:

```
server := &http.Server {
    Addr:           ":8080",
    Handler:        router,
    ReadTimeout:    15*time.Second,
    WriteTimeout:   15*time.Second,
}
go func() {
    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":6060", nil))
}()
log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServe())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to use pprof in combination with [**Gorilla mux**](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/mux#readme-examples). To avoid HTTP 404 errors we need to explicitly specify the route for **`/debug/pprof/{cmd}`** because Gorilla doesn't do prefix routing:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Index))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/cmdline", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Cmdline))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/profile", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Profile))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/symbol", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Symbol))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/trace", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Trace))
router.Handle("/debug/pprof/{cmd}", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Index)) // special handling for Gorilla mux

err := http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:9999", router)
log.Errorf("pprof server listen failed: %v", err) // note: http.ListenAndServe never returns nil
```