# golang no /debug/pprof/profile endpoint for cpu while having everything else

Tags: go, profiling

I'm quite puzzled by a problem that I can't profile my golang program, I have all other endpoints under /debug/pprof but not /debug/pprof/profile for CPU profiling
Have anyone ever stumbled across such issue?

```
go tool pprof http://localhost:7778/debug/pprof/profile
Fetching profile from http://localhost:7778/debug/pprof/profile
Please wait... (30s)
server response: 404 Not Found
```

while

```
/debug/pprof/

profiles:
19  block
31  goroutine
10  heap
0   mutex
11  threadcreate

full goroutine stack dump
```

I setup profiling in this way

```
r := http.NewServeMux()
r.Handle("/debug/pprof/", http.HandlerFunc(pprof.Index))
```

What can be the cause?

Updated: running

```
http.ListenAndServe("localhost:4444", nil)
```

(i.e. starting default http server) fixes the problem for my custom endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, I didn't register all the handlers as done in init here
https://golang.org/src/net/http/pprof/pprof.go

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled the same error as you, I had registered all according to the documentation. In case anyone faced the same problem, it turned out that you need to add `http.DefaultServeMux`, so the complete lines should be:

> ```
>   r := mux.NewRouter()
>
>   r.PathPrefix("/debug/").Handler(http.DefaultServeMux)
>
>   r.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/", pprof.Index)
>   r.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/cmdline", pprof.Cmdline)
>   r.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/profile", pprof.Profile)
>   r.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/symbol", pprof.Symbol)
>   r.HandleFunc("/debug/pprof/trace", pprof.Trace)
> ```

reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52729856/448266)